# Android intentService, how to skip to the next task in the queue?

Tags: android, queue, intentservice

i have an activity that call an intent service.

The intentService download files from internet in backgrounf, but i want to be able to abort a specific download.........

So let's say thta i put 5 files in queue: file 1,2,3,4,5

The intent service start downloading the number 1.
Is there a way to say to the intent service abort what you are doing at the moment in the method handle event  (in this case downloading file 1) and start downloading the next one?

Is it possible to removre element from the queue, so for example while is downloading file 1, remove the file 4 from the queue so that after the number 3 goes straight to the 5?

Tnx

Comment: You have asked 12 questions and not accepted a single answer. That doesn't encourage people to help you. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: sorry i didn't know i had to do that.....i will privide.....